# move on next / prev project left / right with arrow keys

Tags: jquery, keyboard, image-gallery, lightgallery

I have this website https://www.sepulturaimpex.ro/portofoliu-constructii-metalice/  I want to move from one image to another by pressing arrow keys from the keyboard. 
Can u guys help me? 
Thx
I'm trying to use this

```
$(window).bind('keydown', function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 37) {
        console.log('left');
    } else if (e.keyCode == 38) {
        console.log('up');
    } else if (e.keyCode == 39) {
        console.log('right');
    } else if (e.keyCode == 40) {
        console.log('down');
    }
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="customNavigation fhsln"> <a class="button__badge1 prev prev-slide transition"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i></a> <a class="button__badge1 next next-slide transition"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a></div>
```

Comment: StackOverflow is not a coding service, Please provide us with what you have tried yourself to create this and then we can help you from there.

Comment: Paste the code or give idea what your code is doing and how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
var $lg = $(".lightgallery");
$lg.lightGallery(...)

...

$(document).keydown(function (e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  if (e.keyCode === 37) {
    // Left
    $lg.data('lightGallery').goToPrevSlide();
    return false;
  } else if (e.keyCode === 39) {
    // Right
    $lg.data('lightGallery').goToNextSlide();
    return false;
  }
});
```

After `lightGallery` initialization, assign action for `onKeyDown` event and call `goToPrevSlide` or `goToNextSlide` functions according to pressed button.

`return false` is used to avoid horizontal page scroll.